# Finding all method invocations with tree visitor

Tags: sonarqube5.1

I'm converting a simple static analysis rule implemented against bytecode using ASM to work with SonarQube.

I've created a subclass of `BaseTreeVisitor` and overridden the `visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocationTree tree)` method.

When it parses a simple method like

```
public void someMethod() {
  org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat(true);
}
```

The fully qualified name and type of the called method is easily retrievable from the MethodInvocationTree.

However for chained method calls such as

```
public void someMethod() {
  org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat(true).isEqualTo(true);
}
```

Only the terminating `isEqualTo` method call is visible.

How do I detect that assertThat is also called?

Detecting method calls with ASM was trivial. Is there another part of the sonar api I should be using instead of a TreeVisitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was of my own making if

```
super.visitMethodInvocation(mit);
```

Is not called in an overriden `visitMethodInvocation` subsequent calls are not seen.